# Virtual box running ubuntu is not scaling

Tags: virtualbox

I have this issue, where a box running ubuntu is not scaling how it should:

VM

[image: VM]

Setting

[image: Setting]

I get this warning too

[image: I get this warning too]

I have the guest additions installed and I am on a mac.

Comment: If you go to Tools > Preferences > Display, is "Maximum Screen Size" set to "None"? This on the VirtualBox interface and not within the guest window.

Comment: Did you also install VBox Guest Additions / Extensions Pack as it indicated in the notice?

Comment: @Gordster is was not set to none , I've changed it but is the same

Comment: @ThomasWard no i do not ,how do i do that ?

Comment: @Gordster Thanks a lot ! I've played a little bit with those settings and. managed to do it!

Comment: Glad to help! I just posted my response as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to Tools > Preferences > Display, is "Maximum Screen Size" set to "None"? This on the VirtualBox interface and not within the guest window.

After making sure that "Maximum Screen Size" is set to "None" it is best go to the VM window and click View > Virtual Screen 1, and use the "auto scaled %200" option.

Hope that Helps!